# Conversion of RDD to DataFrame using .toDF() When CSV data read using SparkContext (Not sqlContext)

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am a pure new guy in SparkSQL. Please help me anyone. 
My specific question is that if we can convert the RDD `hospitalDataText` to a DataFrame(using `.toDF()`) where `hospitalDataText` has read the csv file using Spark Context(Not using `sqlContext.read.csv("path")`).
**SO WHY WE CANNOT WRITE** `header.toDF()` ? If I am trying to convert the variable `header` RDD to DataFrame it is throwing an error that: `value toDF is not a member of String`. **Why?** ***My main purpose is that I want to view the data of the variable `header` RDD using `.show()` function*** and therefore why I am unable to convert the RDD to a DataFrame? Please check the code given below! **It is looks like DOUBLE-STANDARD**  :'(

```
scala> val hospitalDataText = sc.textFile("/Users/TheBhaskarDas/Desktop/services.csv")
hospitalDataText: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = /Users/TheBhaskarDas/Desktop/services.csv MapPartitionsRDD[39] at textFile at <console>:33

scala> val header = hospitalDataText.first() //Remove the header
header: String = uhid,locationid,doctorid,billdate,servicename,servicequantity,starttime,endtime,servicetype,servicecategory,deptname
```

> scala> header.toDF()
>
> ```
> <console>:38: error: value toDF is not a member of String
>        header.toDF()
>
>               ^
> ```

```
scala> val hospitalData = hospitalDataText.filter(a => a != header)
hospitalData: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[40] at filter at <console>:37

scala> val m = hospitalData.toDF()
m: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string]

scala> println(m)
[value: string]

scala> m.show()
+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|32d84f8b9c5193838...|
|32d84f8b9c5193838...|
|213d66cb9aae532ff...|
|222f8f1766ed4e7c6...|
|222f8f1766ed4e7c6...|
|993f608405800f97d...|
|993f608405800f97d...|
|fa14c3845a8f1f6b0...|
|6e2899a575a534a1d...|
|6e2899a575a534a1d...|
|1f1603e3c0a0db5e6...|
|508a4fbea4752771f...|
|5f33395ae7422c3cf...|
|5f33395ae7422c3cf...|
|4ef07783ce800fc5d...|
|70c13902c9c9ccd02...|
|70c13902c9c9ccd02...|
|a950feff6911ab5e4...|
|b1a0d427adfdc4f7e...|
|b1a0d427adfdc4f7e...|
+--------------------+
only showing top 20 rows


scala> m.show(1)
+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|32d84f8b9c5193838...|
+--------------------+
only showing top 1 row


scala> m.show(1,true)
+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|32d84f8b9c5193838...|
+--------------------+
only showing top 1 row


scala> m.show(1,2)
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|   32|
+-----+
only showing top 1 row
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You keep saying `header` is an `RDD` while the output you posted clearly shows that `header` is a `String`.  `first()` does not return an `RDD`.  You can't use `show()` on a `String`, but you can use `println`.

Comment: OMG! Thankful to you that you have opened my eyes. Thanks :) I am sorry I didn't get my mistake :(
Thanks again. :)